# Are holomorphic an anti-holomorphic vectors or forms in any way fundamentally different?

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry

The question is stated in the title. Could one introduce all the complex geometry concepts just by using the "anti-" objects instead? Or is it just a $Z_2$ symmetry thing like it sometimes is with complex problems?

Comment: In terms of functions you certainly don't get far with anti-holomorphic ones, as they are not closed under composition.

Comment: @LeonidKovalev: Why? What makes $\bar \partial$ and $\bar z$ so much worse than $\partial$ and $z$?

Comment: 1) The identity map is holomorphic; it is not antiholomorphic. 2) If you pull a $(p,q)$-form by a holomorphic map, you get another $(p,q)$-form; but pulling it by an antiholomorphic map gives you a $(q,p)$ form, an element of a different space. Etc. It's like comparing positive numbers to negative: as long as you stick to addition, there is a perfect symmetry, but once you start considering multiplication, positive numbers win.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The identity map is holomorphic; it is not antiholomorphic.
2. If you pull a (p,q)-form by a holomorphic map, you get another (p,q)-form; but pulling it by an antiholomorphic map gives you a (q,p) form, an element of a different space. Etc. It's like comparing positive numbers to negative: as long as you stick to addition, there is a perfect symmetry, but once you start considering multiplication, positive numbers win.

Comment: Very nice and crisp explanation.